# Debezium mongo source connector: topics created with names having invalid characters

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using Debezium Mongo source connector. As the [documentation states](https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mongodb/) "The name of the Kafka topics always takes the form logicalName.databaseName.collectionName". I am running into a problem where the original mongo collection names include characters that are invalid to be used as topic names. For example, "exampleofcollection@name". This will make mongo source connector fail when creating a topic. 
Is there a way to circumvent this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this is a bug we should handle. Could you please raise an issue in Debezium's Jira? Also at what time the problem happens? Cannot it be circumvent by using https://debezium.io/docs/configuration/topic-routing/ to route it to a different topic?

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Jiri! In theory that topic transform could have fixed the problem, but for some reason it's not working. `transforms=Reroute;transforms.Reroute.type=io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter;transforms.Reroute.topic.regex=(.*)my@collection(.*);transforms.Reroute.topic.replacement=$1my_collection`. Error: WARN [Producer clientId=producer-49] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 604 : {testnl.testnl.my@collection=INVALID_TOPIC_EXCEPTION}. Do you see anything wrong with the transform? The problem happens when the connecter tries to write to the kafka topic.